# How to make server side requests (API) with a catch-all React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm relatively new to react/redux and I've encountered a problem.

Say for example I want to search for an item.

```
export default function getSearchItems(itemName) {
  return dispatch => {
    // Show that it is requesting, will be updated after.
    dispatch(requestItems(itemName));
    // URL todo.
    return fetch('/search')
    .then(
      response => response.json(),
      error => dispatch(requestItemsFailure(itemName))
    ).then(
      json => dispatch(requestItemsSuccess(itemName, json))
    );
  };
}
```

Here I've made a request to the url /search. But because I've opted to use React Router v4's client side routing, I did this on the server-side.

```
// Manage Routes
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../build/index.html'));
});

// Search Grab data
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
  console.log('hit');
  res.status(200).json(
    {item:"test"}
  );
});
```

Since I used a "catch-all" method as described here [in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually?noredirect=1&lq=1), I can no longer do something like "/login" and have it go to the correct component immediately.

How can I make the two work together properly?

Comment: the catch-all case should be with a `*` not a `/` and you can define the `/login` in your react routes and also it will be better if you prefix your routes in the backend with `/api` for example your `/search` will be `/api/search` also you can define any routes for the backend before the catch-all case

Comment: Oh yes you're correct, it was previously with a /*. /login is defined in the react routes as
`<Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
`. Even when I originally put the /search route above the catch all it would return the HTML as the response instead which meant that it was hitting the catch-all route afterwards?

Comment: without `/` just `*` so any request will be redirected to the index.html if the route is not defined in your backend routes before the catch-all case

Comment: in other words your catch-all case should be the last case of handling the routes

Comment: Yes you're correct. I'd flag you as the right answer but you answered it as a comment! Thanks a lot for the help. For a second I thought of how I could make a 404 page if the catch-all handles everything, but I could just do it on the client-side as well with react-router. Simple mistake on my part thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: glad your problem is solved and yes you can handle the 404 on the client side.